# Creating an object with array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array of object that will have multiple children. I have a table with data like this:

```
| PARENT   | CHILD  |
---------------------
| 123456   | 123    |
| 123456   | 124    |
| 123456   | 125    |
| 123457   | 345    |
| 123457   | 346    |
| 123457   | 347    |
....
```

I wish to get an array similar to this:

`var arr_nos = { 123456 : [123, 124, 125], 123457 : [345, 346, 347]}`

During a loop, I have this:

```
var arr_nos = [];
$('#table tbody tr').each(function( index ) {
   var parent_no = elem.find('.parent_no').html();
   var child_id = elem.find('.child_id ').html();
   if(parent_no != '') {
      child = [
         child_id
      ]
      arr_nos.push(parent_no, child);
   }

});
```

But this results in:

```
["123456", Array(1), "123456", Array(1),"123456", Array(1), "123457", Array(1), "123457", Array(1), "123457", Array(1)]
```

Comment: So your example that you want to get `var arr_nos = { 123456 : [123, 124, 125], 123457 : [345, 346, 347]}` is an object of arrays

Comment: You said you want to get object but you create array and push values to it

Comment: Your title says you want a multidimensional array, but your sample suggests it is just an object with value as an array. So what is it?

Comment: Yes, my title is incorrect. The example is what I am trying to acheive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this loop :

```js
var arr_nos = {};
$('#table tbody tr').each(function( index,elem ) {
   var parent_no = $(elem).find('.parent_no').html();
   var child_id = $(elem).find('.child_id ').html();
   if(parent_no != '') {
      if(!arr_nos[parent_no]) arr_nos[parent_no] = [];
      arr_nos[parent_no].push(child_id);
   }

});

console.log(arr_nos);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th class='parent_no'>1</th>
    <th class='child_id'>11</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='parent_no'>2</th>
    <th class='child_id'>22</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='parent_no'>3</th>
    <th class='child_id'>33</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='parent_no'>2</th>
    <th class='child_id'>444</th>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @JudsonCooper your wellcome :) don't forget upvote ,my friend.

Answer (score 0):

To get the object of arrays in your example you would have to do

```
  arr_nos[parent_no] = child
```

and would have to declare the object as

```
arr_nos = {}
```

instead of

```
arr_nos = []
```

---

But this is an object of arrays, not an array of objects. Either your example is wrong, or your definition is wrong

I'm not sure how to obtain your specific example with `{123456: [123, 124, 125], 123457: [345, 346, 347]}`. You'll have to specify what criteria you have to make decide what the keys of this object are.

Comment: There will be multiple parents with the same id (parent_no). I will edit the question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var arr_nos = []
arr_nos.push(parent_no, child)
```

do:

```
let arr_nos = {}
arr_nos[parent_no] = [...arr_nos[parent_no], child]
```

Comment: This is closer, but only adds one child.

Comment: @JudsonCooper check now